# UISwipeGestureRecognizer fails to execute some times

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiswipegesturerecognizer

In my application I have added a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to navigate between `viewControllers`, but sometimes it fails to perform action on swipe gesture. I have simply added the swipe left and swipe right gesture in my `viewDidLoad` of parent `viewController` as i wanted to add the same in all my child `viewControllers`.

```
//Adding swipe gesture recognizers
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftGesture=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightNavigationButtonTapped)];
swipeLeftGesture.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftGesture];
swipeLeftGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightGesture=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftNavigationButtonTapped)];
swipeRightGesture.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightGesture];
swipeRightGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
```

I also added logs to check that when the swipe is being missed like below.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
NSLog(@"touched for event %@", event.class);
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
 shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGesture {
NSLog(@"gesture failed %@", otherGesture.class);
return YES;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:      (UITouch *)touch{
 NSLog(@"touch %@", gestureRecognizer.class);
 return YES;
 }
```

In my case when the swipe is working correct, this is the log:

```
<Warning>: touch UISwipeGestureRecognizer
<Warning>: touch UISwipeGestureRecognizer
<Warning>: gesture failed _UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer
<Warning>: gesture failed _UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer
<Warning>: gesture failed UISwipeGestureRecognizer
<Warning>: gesture failed _UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer
<Warning>: gesture failed _UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer
<Warning>: touched for event UITouchesEvent
```

and when the swipe is not working correct this is the log:

```
<Warning>: touch UISwipeGestureRecognizer
<Warning>: touch UISwipeGestureRecognizer
<Warning>: gesture failed UISwipeGestureRecognizer
<Warning>: gesture failed _UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer
<Warning>: gesture failed _UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer
<Warning>: gesture failed _UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer
<Warning>: gesture failed _UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer
<Warning>: touched for event UITouchesEvent
```

Right now I am not able to understand the actual issue occurring in my case and what could be the issue. Please let me know if you have idea regarding why this issue could be occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning `NO`in
`-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
 shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGesture`? Because that's the default behavior and this simple UISwipGestureRecognizer setup is working for me.

Comment: Hi Robert, I have tried the default behavior but it is still causing the issue. In start it was my default implementation only, i added the extra methods just to check why my swipe is getting missed sometimes. The probability of miss is low, like would say around 10% but it is still an issue. I feel like something is consuming my gesture in middle and it is not getting to my getureRecognizer. Is there any way i could see stack trace for my event.

Comment: it may be that sometimes one of the two gesture recognizers cancels the other and then fails himself? try adding only one and see if it works better, or return `YES`in `-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`. Sorry , but I do not know any other way to trace the events than logging them in the gesture recognizer (subclass it by importing `<UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>`in the subclass) or its delegate.